# Flutter: Set default TextField property across the whole app

Tags: flutter

Is there a way I can set the default `TextField textCapitilisation` to `TextCapitilisation.sentences` so that I do not have to add to it every `TextField`?

Ideally in ThemeData?

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do that with ThemeDate but you can create your own TextField widget that build a TextField with your capitalization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @ F Perroch said, I don't think that is possible too but you can create a `Custom TextField` for all of your `TextField` Widgets and use them where appropriate like the exmaple below:

**Create a CustomTextField widget like below**

```
class CustomTextField extends StatelessWidget {
  /// define property of text fields you want here
  final String hinText;
  final String labelText;
  final Widget icon;
  final TextStyle labelStyle;
  CustomTextField({this.hinText, this.labelText, this.icon, this.labelStyle});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextField(
      // set your text capitalization here
      textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.sentences,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        /// set other properties here
        hintText: hinText,
        labelText: labelText,
        labelStyle: labelStyle,
        prefixIcon: icon,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Call the CustomTextField widget anywhere like below**

```
CustomTextField(
  hintText: 'Hello',
  labelText: 'Hi there',
  labelStyle: TextStyle(....),
  icon: Icon(Icons.person)
),
```

I hope this answers your question.